# XSD Restriction on local complexType elements

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction, complextype

I have a schema that has a local complexType element as follows.

```
<xs:complexType name="AddressType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> 
        <xs:element name="Line2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100"/>
        <xs:element name="Location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="XCoordinate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="YCoordinate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

I am trying to extend this complexType as follows

```
<xs:complexType name="InternalAddressType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AddressType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Location" >
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am getting the following error

```
**Error for type 'InternalAddressType'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
```

Can anyone please help me understand what am I doing worng. It seems that the problem is that the Location is a local ComplexType. But I can not change that since I am getting the xsd from the client and need to extend just the Loaction. How can I solve this situation. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: You can't restrict `Location` because it is defined by a local `complexType`.

Even a `restriction` of `AddressType` that includes the exact same components will fail similarly:

```
  <xs:complexType name="InternalAddressType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AddressType">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Line1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/> 
            <xs:element name="Line2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100"/>
            <xs:element name="Location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="XCoordinate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <xs:element name="YCoordinate" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Without the attempt to override `Location`, the above definition would be fine.

Given that you cannot change `AddressType` to pull out the local `complexType`, what can you do?  Depending upon your requirements, perhaps you might extend `AddressType` using `xs:extension` and define your own `MyLocation` element that is as you wish, ignoring the original `Location` element (or never creating it -- it's optional).  Or, perhaps a fully decoupled definition of InternalAddressType works for you.  If neither of these possibilities satisfy your purposes, state in the comments the requirements of your final goal, and perhaps we can find something suitably close.

Comment: Hi @kjhughes, thank you for your reply. What I am trying to do is given the above schema ("InternalAddressType") I want to create another schema ("InternalAddressType_1") which has the same structure as the above one but with more elements. I could have gone for Extension but the problem is that it will not allow me to make any changes in the "Location". I would have to create a new type called Location_1 and add elements in there. Thereby I will then have to maintain two different structures of Location both having partial data. Which is a problem if there are multiple instances of Location.

Comment: Planning to further extend/restrict `InternalAddressType` to `InternalAddressType_1` only exacerbates the original problem that the way `Location` is defined in `AddressType` (which is out your control) it cannot be overridden.  Practically speaking, I think you're going to have to accept that you just can't share the definition of `AddressType`'s `Location` given these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use XSD 1.1 (sadly, not many people are), then you can define your restriction in the form of an assertion - which because it states precisely what **additional** conditions you want to apply, is a much more usable mechanism, in my opinion, than providing an alternative content model that has to maintain a close correspondence to the original.

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon and Xerces.

The other solution is two-phase validation. Use the client's schema to ensure that the document conforms to the constraints defined by the client, then use your own schema (or other technology) to validate that it conforms to the additional constraints defined by you. That may well be an architecturally cleaner approach anyway.